# which component template is loaded first among parent and child component

Tags: angular

I have 2 components Parent and Child component

inside parent component template I am using the selector of the Child component.

which component template is loaded first after running the application on a local server

and which component constructor() and ngOnInit() will get executed first ?

when i debug it in my case it executing in the following way

1) constructor() of parent

2)constructor() of child

3)ngOnInit() of parent

4) ngOnInit() of child

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: my question is, alternate constructors are invoked, I mean 1st parents and then child's component constructor so in case of template which template is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The sequence you mentioned is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Always the parent component is loaded first as child component is a part of parent component it cannot be loaded before parent component